# How can I get Syslogging to work on the JVM?

Tags: java, scala, syslog

I want to do syslogging from Java. There is a log4j appender, but it doesn't seem to work (for me anyway ... though Google results show many others with this issue still unresolved).

I'm trying to debug the appender, so I've written the following script based upon [RFC3164](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt)

It runs, but no logging appears in the syslog.

```
// scala
import java.io._
import java.net._
val ds = new DatagramSocket()
val fullMsg = "<11>May 26 14:47:22 Hello World"
val packet = new DatagramPacket(fullMsg.getBytes("UTF-8"), fullMsg.length, 
  InetAddress.getLocalHost, 514)
ds send packet
ds.close
```

I also tried using /bin/nc, but it doesn't work either.

```
echo "<14>May 26 15:23:33 Hello world" > nc -u localhost 514
```

The Ubuntu command /usr/bin/logger **does** work, however.

```
logger -p user.info hello world
# logs: May 26 15:25:10 dsupport2 jem: hello world
```

What could I be doing wrong?

**Edit**

Both nc & the scala generate the following packet:

```
jem@dsupport2:~/projects/log4j$ grep -A 10 514 out
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:37920(unknown) -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:514(syslog)
Version: 4   Total Lenght: 63   TTL: 64
Packet Number: 4

---[ UDP Data ]------------------------------------------------------

<14>May 26 15:26:33 Hello world 22
```

It seems I cannot get /usr/bin/logger (the one that works) to talk remotely. I assume you're supposed to set up the local syslogd as a relay.

**Edit**

Using nc, wireshark shows the message to be formatted OK, but that the port is unreachable.

Comment: I think this is a question more appropriate to serverfault than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network firewall in Ubuntu needs to be explicitly told to allow traffic to a given port, this includes Syslog.

Comment: The firewall is not active.

jem@dsupport2:~/projects$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

Comment: well, ufw is not enabled, but wireshark says destination unreachable ... what other way could the port be blocked?

Comment: Use the GUI version instead.  I do not know which technology is used under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sniffing the local network traffic to see if the log messages are actually sent, if they seem well-formed, etc? You could use [nast](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/nast.8.html) or something like it.

Comment: Did not know it was possible when the traffic is loopback. But I haven't tried nast, so here goes ...

Comment: `nast` was just the first thing I found on Google, I just assumed it can sniff loopback. WireShark can, anyway: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback

Answer (score 1):

Syslogd is probaby not listening on an IP socket but a unix domain socket. The standard socket is `/dev/log`. You will need to use a library such as [JUDS](http://github.com/mcfunley/juds) to connect to this socket. This will give an OutputStream that you can write the log record to.